# Google Places API: how to listen to error events?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-places-api, rate-limiting

I'm using Google Places Autocomplete API in my frontend JS app like so:

```js
const place = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputRef.value, options)
google.maps.event.addListener(place, 'place_changed', function () {
  const { place_id: placeIdGoogle, formatted_address: name } = place.getPlace()
  // ...
})
```

I want to catch errors, especially rate limit errors to handle them gracefully and show something to the user.

Is there an [event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event) I can subscribe to?

Answer (score 0):

### Programmatically retrieving Place Autocomplete Service predictions and Place details

What you are using is the Autocomplete widget as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#add-autocomplete). But since the widget already handles the process for you, there's not much of a freedom in handling the response of the API.

What you can do is try to make one programmatically. Please see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) to learn more.

In doing so, you can use three `classes`:

1. `google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()` for fetching predictions
2. `google.maps.places.PlacesService()` and use the `getDetails` method to fetch the details of a place your end user chooses.
3. `google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken()` to make sure that your bills are optimized(since using session tokens will make your autocomplete queries free. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/session-tokens) to learn more.)

The reason why you should programmatically implement the Places API to be able to handle errors is because the `AutocompleteService()` and `PlacesService().getDetails()` have a `STATUS` parameter which returns a status code / text.

You can do so in this way:

```js
function initService() {
  var li;
  var input = document.getElementById("location");
  
  var autoService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  var sessionToken = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken();
  
  input.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpFunc);
  function keyUpFunc() {
    var ul = document.getElementById('results');
    while(ul.firstChild)ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    autoService.getPlacePredictions({ 
      input: input.value ,
      sessionToken: sessionToken
    }, displaySuggestions);
  }
  
  
  var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
        // if the status returned is not 'OK', which means an error, it would send an alert with the text code of the error
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }
    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.setAttribute("data-id", prediction.place_id);
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prediction.description));
      li.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
        var place_id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
        input.value = this.innerHTML;
        getPlaceDet(place_id);
      });
      document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);

    });
  };

  function getPlaceDet(placeId){
    var request = {
      placeId: placeId,
      sessionToken: sessionToken,
      fields: ['name', 'vicinity']
    }; 
    var placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
    placeService.getDetails(request, callback);
    function callback(place, status) {
            // if the status returned is not 'OK', which means an error, it would send an alert with the text code of the error.
            if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    alert(status)
            }
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log('Name: ' + place.name +' Vicinity: ' + place.vicinity );
        sessionToken = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken();
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Autocomplete Service</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="right-panel">
      <input type="text" id="location">
      <p>Place suggestions</p>
      <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initService"
            async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just take note of where I put my comment `// if the status returned is not 'OK', which means an error, it would send an alert with the text code of the error.`

Just see this link to know more about `PlacesAutocompleteStatus`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#PlacesAutocompleteStatus

And this link to know more about `PlacesDetailsStatus`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlacesDetailsStatus

Hope this helps!